# What's wrong with my nine patch image?

Tags: android, nine-patch

I'm trying to make a patch 9 file for button so it looks like a drop down. The file worked fine before I tried to add the little drop down icon to the image and have it not stretch that part. This is what it looks like in the editor:
[image: This is what it looks like in the editor]

Here is the actual [file](http://nkonecny.com/menu.9.png)

Comment: What do you want it to look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line on the right should probably be one continuous line in the center so that text is placed in the middle of the dropdown.

Comment: Actually I believe it HAS to be a single line on the right edge.

Comment: No, the left edge represents the "stretchable" area, the right edge represents the area that android is allowed to fill the image with either child views or text.  The right and bottom edge are basically used to specify padding.  The left and top edge are used to specify stretching.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. That fixed it!

Comment: No, the right side is for the content and not for stretching.A good exmplenation can be found here [link to nine-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch)